# How do I load a new script after the page is done loading?

Tags: javascript

I have two separate script files (script1.js, script2.js). Each of the files has its own functions/variables defined in it. For the sake of simplicity, I will assume each file holds a separate variable. So the files will look like:

**script1.js**

```
var x = 2;
```

**script2.js**

```
var y = 2;
```

I am using the scripts in index.html:

**index.html**

```
<button onclick="change()">Change script</button>
<script id="file" src="script1.js"></script>
<script>
  function change() {
    var file = document.getElementById("file");
    if(file.src.slice(-10) == "script1.js") {
      file.src = "script2.js";
    } else {
      file.src = "script1.js";
    }
  }
</script>
```

But when I change the `src` attribute for the script, the loaded script does not change. So even after switching scripts, `x` has the value `2` while `y` is undefined.

How do I switch the script after the page has finished loading?

Comment: Normally you would just load both scripts when the page loads, instead of switching back and forth like this...

Comment: But how do I accomplish this?

Comment: And one thing to add: I want the new script to replace the old one, not just get loaded.

Comment: I don't think it will work that way.

Comment: Sounds like an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) … can you describe what you want to _achieve_ by this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a new script in order to loaded it, the problem is that you also want to maintain the position of the script.

So here I wrote an example that will replace the old script and insert the new one at the same position.

Read the comment to understand how this work.

```js
  function change() {
    var file = document.getElementById("file"); // get the script you want to change
    var newscript = document.createElement("script"); // create new script
    newscript.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" // set the new script src
    newscript.setAttribute("id","file"); // set the id to the same id as the old script
    newscript.type = 'text/javascript';
    file.parentNode.insertBefore(newscript, file); // insert the new script before the old one
    file.remove() // remove the old script
    
    var callback= function(){ // when the script has been loded then test and see if jQuery is working now
      $("body").append("<p>Jq loaded</p>"); // no error then jQuery has been loaded
    }
    newscript.onreadystatechange = callback;
    newscript.onload = callback;
  
  }
```

```html
<script id="file" src="script1.js"></script>
<button onclick="change()">Change script</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you want to accomplish, but as far as loading of javascript is concern, you can use:

```
$("#id_of_button").click(function(){
$.getScript('helloworld.js', function() {
    //do whatever you want to accomplish here....
});
```

});

More detail [here](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-load-javascript-at-runtime-with-jquery/)

A better way may be to keep the related code in separate functions in same js file and calling the specific function to override the logic based upon your condition check. Though I'm still not clear what you are trying to achieve. Could I get some scenario based idea to get it clear?

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I want. I want the new script to replace the old script (such that everything - variables/functions - in the old script gets erased), plus I would prefer it to be done in vanilla javascript.

Comment: A better way may be to keep the related code in separate functions in same js file and calling the specific function to override the logic based upon your condition check. Though I'm still not clear what you are trying to achieve. Could I get some scenario based idea to get it clear?

Comment: @Wais Kamal Read my solution it will do exakt what you want

Comment: @ShaileshSaxena in my scenario the script files are modules of a web app. Instead of loading both modules when the user only needs one, why not load the second module only when the user needs it?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mvMZOR

**HTML**

```
<button type="button">Change script</button>
<script id="file" src="script1.js"></script>
```

**Javascript**

```
var index = 1;
var scriptId = 'file';
var button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // Remove the old script
  document.getElementById(scriptId).remove();
  // Create the new one
  var s = document.createElement('script');
  // Add the id you want, in this case "file"
  s.id = scriptId;
  // It will return "script1.js" or "script2.js" alternatively
  s.src = 'script' + (index++ % 2 + 1) + '.js'; 
  // Append your new script at the end of your body
  document.querySelector('body').append(s);
});
```